# Tkinter calculator fails to update label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, calculator

I tried making a simple integer sign calculator using tkinter.  It has a class with two different functions.  The second function is supposed to be initiated when the user presses the "Enter" button.  When I run the code the window comes up just as it is supposed to.  But when I type and hit "Enter" the second function fails to run and does not update the label.  I want for it to update as either "This number is positive.", "This number is 0.", or "This number is negative."  Instead it remains blank.

I doubt it is relevant, but I made this program in PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4, and I am using Python 3.5 (32-bit).

```
import tkinter

class IntegerSign:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Integer Sign Calculator")
        self.window.geometry("300x150")

        self.number_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)

        self.solution_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)

        self.number_label = tkinter.Label(self.number_frame, text="Enter an integer:")
        self.number_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.number_frame, width=10)
        self.number_label.pack(side='left')
        self.number_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.statement = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.solution_label = tkinter.Label(self.solution_frame, textvariable=self.statement)

        self.statement = tkinter.Label(self.solution_frame, textvariable=self.statement)

        self.solution_label.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Enter', command=self.calc_answer)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Quit', command=self.window.destroy)

        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        self.number_frame.pack()
        self.solution_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc_answer(self):
        self.number = int(self.number_entry.get())
        self.statement = tkinter.StringVar()

        if self.number > 0:
            self.statement = "This number is positive."
        elif self.number == 0:
            self.statement = "This number is 0."
        else:
            self.statement = "This number is negative."
IntegerSign()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem: in your constructor you initialize a variable named self.statement to a StringVar and then initialize again to a Label.  After that second initialization, you have no way of accessing the first object.  You need to use two different names.

The second problem: in your event handler, `calc_answer`, you create a new object named `self.statement`, but instead you need to `set` a new value into the old one (see [docs](http:////http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html)).  Here is a modified version of your program that works as intended:

```
import tkinter

class IntegerSign:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Integer Sign Calculator")
        self.window.geometry("300x150")

        self.number_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)

        self.solution_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)

        self.number_label = tkinter.Label(self.number_frame, text="Enter an integer:")
        self.number_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.number_frame, width=10)
        self.number_label.pack(side='left')
        self.number_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.solution_string = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.solution_label = tkinter.Label(self.solution_frame, textvariable=self.solution_string)

        self.statement = tkinter.Label(self.solution_frame, textvariable=self.solution_string)

        self.solution_label.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Enter', command=self.calc_answer)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Quit', command=self.window.destroy)

        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        self.number_frame.pack()
        self.solution_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc_answer(self):
        self.number = int(self.number_entry.get())

        if self.number > 0:
            self.solution_string.set("This number is positive.")
        elif self.number == 0:
            self.solution_string.set("This number is 0.")
        else:
            self.solution_string.set("This number is negative.")
IntegerSign()
```

This code works but contains a bad practice that I recommend you fix.  The function `tkinter.mainloop()` is essentially an infinite loop, and you have placed it inside the constructor.  Thus the constructor won't return the way a constructor is normally supposed to.  Take that statement out of the `__init__` function and put it at the end, after the call to `IntegerSign`, and make this a pattern to be used in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a StringVar you need to use the `set` method.
Right now all you did was re-assign the variable. You can also set a stringvar's (default) value by giving it a value when you first initialize it. e.g. - `var = tk.StringVar(value="some value")`

Edit: Didn't see that you also set self.statement to be the label widget... This would work if you used the method all the way at the bottom of this answer, and disregarded (optionally) stringvar's entirely. But, when you do this you can think of it as sticky notes. You stuck a sticky note that says "this variable holds this value", then you re-assigned the variable put another sticky note over the previous one that says "it now holds this value" as a really loose visual analogy.

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> statement = tk.StringVar()
>>> type(statement)
>>> <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>
>>> statement = "This number is positive"
>>> type(statement)
>>> <class 'str'>
>>> statement = tk.StringVar()
>>> statement.set("This number is positive")
>>> statement.get()
'This number is positive'
>>> type(statement)
>>> <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>
```

Alternatively you could just change the labels text by doing `label_widget['text'] = 'new_text'`